# How to Configure WEBrick to Display XHTML and its CSS

Tags: css, ruby, xhtml, webrick

I cannot make WEBrick display an XHTML page and its associated CSS - the exact same file with an 'html' extension works perfectly, but it fails with an 'xhtml' extension. How can I configure WEBrick to display XHTML and its CSS?.

I've tried this:

```
require 'webrick'

def start_webrick(config = {})
  config.update(:Port => 5000, :DocumentRoot => '\path\to\my\file\')
  server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(config)
  yield server if block_given?
  ['INT', 'TERM'].each {|signal|
    trap(signal) {server.shutdown}
  }
  server.start
end

start_webrick
```

I've also tried this:

```
require 'webrick'

# WEBrick::HTTPUtils::DefaultMimeTypes['xhtml'] = 'application/xhtml+xml'

# var = File.read('/PD/Dev/Data/Web/Public/index.xhtml')
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 5000, :DocumentRoot => '\path\to\my\file\')
server.mount_proc('/') {|request, response| response.body}
trap("INT") {server.shutdown}
server.start
```

I'm using Ruby 2.7, and I've also changed the default Mime type as in the above comment. If I uncomment the 'File.read...' above and change the 'response.body' to 'response = var', I get the file displayed but not as expected.

I'm very new to this and would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: XHTML is a defined MIME type in WEBrick but it is defined as text/html [Source](https://github.com/ruby/webrick/blob/master/lib/webrick/httputils.rb#L112) so I have no idea how this statement: *"...the exact same file with an 'html' extension works perfectly, but it fails with an 'xhtml' extension." is true. Can you provide some additional context as to what you are expecting vs what you are receiving?

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your interest (and sorry about my garbled text and code listing). What I mean is if I change the file extension from 'xhtml' to 'html' it works as advertised, but I cannot figure out how to have WEBrick correctly display a file with an 'xhtml' extension; by 'correct', I mean with its CSS formatting.